# I don't get the return of cross-validation to template-driven forms

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, primeng

I am trying to get `true` to return when the passwords aren't the same.

My component

```
this.restrict = new FormGroup({
  email: new FormControl(this.user.email),
  newPassword: new FormControl ('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('(?=\\D*\\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]).{6,30}')]),
  confirmPassword: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
}, {validators: this.pwdMatchValidator});

get newPassword() { return this.restrict.get('newPassword');}
get confirmPassword() { return this.restrict.get('confirmPassword');}

pwdMatchValidator(frm: FormGroup) {
  let pass = frm.get('newPassword').value;
  let confirmPass = frm.get('confirmPassword').value;
  console.log(pass);
  console.log(confirmPass);
  return pass === confirmPass ? null: { notSame: true};
}
```

In the template I have

```
<p-password formControlName="confirmPassword"></p-password>
<small class="p-error" *ngIf="confirmPassword.hasError('required')">No puede estar vacio</small>
<small class="p-error" *ngIf="confirmPassword.hasError('minlength')">Debe ser de hasta 6 caracteres.</small>
<small class="p-error" *ngIf="confirmPassword.hasError('notSame', 'passwords')">Las contraseñan son diferentes.</small>
<button pButton pRipple label="Save" icon="pi pi-check" class="p-button-text" [disabled]="!restrict.valid"></button>
```

Currently the answer I get is always `false`

The `concole.log(pass);` and `console.log(confirmPass);` do they work and the save button is still disabled because the field was not validated, then how can I get `notSame`? I tried:

```
{{ restrict.get('confirmPassword').errors?.notSame }}
{{ restrict.get('confirmPassword').errors }}
{{ confirmPassword.hasError('notSame') }}
```

In angular [examples](https://angular.io/generated/zips/form-validation/form-validation.zip), they show a shape that in my case (angular 12) doesn't work

In the Angular documentation I can't find a satisfactory concept of how to handle returns, could you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

You validator is set on the **FormGroup** not the `confirmPassword` formcontrol, so the check you need to do is actually on the parentForm:

```
<small ngIf="restrict.hasError('notSame')">...</small>
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pkxpaa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Thank for answering, then when it is cross-validation the return alway is parentForm? Or there is some characteristic that positions it as parentForm?

Comment: You have placed your validator on the parent yourself => `this.restrict = new FormGroup({ }, {validators: this.pwdMatchValidator});`

Comment: Easiest is if you want to perform crossvalidation, parentform or nested parentform would be the way to go I'd say, otherwise you need to traverse upwards to get the other(s) controls you want to compare with. If you set the validator on for example the confirmPassword, then you would need to traverse up to the parent to get the password form control.